# Php Script (to read Shared Server data and write locally) works well on one machine but times out on another

Tags: php, json, server

I have a php script that Queries folder structure at Network location and writes processed array to a Json file.
This works well for on a one machine.
However, when I try to hit the same URL with a different machine, the php keeps on loading and does not loads result.
It Just times out

My URL is like:

```
> http://localhost/test.php?filename=fileName.json&path=\\Server\folder
```

Both machines have Apace Server Installed.
Both can access the Server share(I checked by opening the folder, but not sure if web browser does it another way. If there is a way to check if URL can access the path, please share)
There is no Exception thrown.
Note:
I know i have to be specific, but at this point i don't know what "specific details" would include.

Thanks for inputs.

Comment: That URL clearly is invalid. You have to encode the path parameters value in the URL!

Comment: @arkascha : I did add the Values in URL. These values (fileName.json adn "\\Server\Folder\")are for reference. Also this works perfectly on one machine. But fails on another. I am unable to figure out what could that be

Comment: I know. You wrote that in your question. No need to repeat. Nevertheless that URL is invalid. It contains characters not allowed at that position ( \\ ). It might well be that this works sometimes, but it is "sloppy", not a clean setup. You should correct it. The same applies for the `.` in the filename parameter, by the way. You should start reading some basic information about URL syntax.

Comment: Okay, so should that be 
 http://localhost/test.php?filename="fileName.json"&path="\\Server\folder" ?

Comment: What? No! Why "localhost"? Once more: you _cannot_ use any arbitrary characters inside your URL query part. In this case the backslash is an issue. You cannot use it, you have to encode it. Note: I do not claim that is the issue here. It is just _an_ issue. _Start reading documentation!_ You will never learn to program without reading documentation when you face an issue, sorry.